# UINavigationController within a UITabBarController, setting the navigation controller title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have a UINavigationController within a UITabBarController. Everything is working fine, however I can't set the title for the navigation controller. I have tried several different methods and googled around but there seems to be no solution for this problem.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Sam

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760634/cocoa-touch-setting-uinavigationcontrollers-title-doesnt-work

Comment: Surely you should be specifying the view controller's title in the view controller and then the navigation controller will have the correct title applied?

Comment: I am specifying the title in the view controller. Thanks. Sam.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found the answer in the end, it was:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Your Title"
```

Works for every case.

Comment: This should work. Check to make sure `self.navigationItem` does not return nil. If nil, check your connections.

Comment: If you are loading from a xib or from storyboard, try dragging a navigationItem to your viewController, if there is none

Answer (score 1):

For me the following works fine:

Initiate the controllers in `appDelegateDidFinishLaunching:`Method:

```
UINavigationController *navContr1;
UINavigationController *navContr2;

UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;

viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];



navContr1       = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1] autorelease];
navContr2       = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2] autorelease];


self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
//self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navContr1, navContr2, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

with this done, in your different viewControllers `initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` - Method you can change the title with the following line:

```
self.title = @"Your Title";
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already fairly deep in my app so this so i can't use this exact method but mine isn't that different. However doing self.title doesn't work, self.title just sets the title for the tab bar. Thanks though!

Comment: what about self.navigationController.title = @"new title" ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `UIViewController` class in the docs. There is a property pointing to the `UINavigationItem` which then has a property pointing to the `title`. If the pointer to the navigation item returns nil, you must have not wired the controllers together correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `self.title` always sets the tile of the `rootViewController` object of your ViewController.

If you have your `viewController` & the `rootViewController` is `UINavigationController`, then `self.title` will set the title of `UINavigationController`.

Similarly, if you have initialized a `UITabViewController` with the `UIViewController` objects, then the `self.title` will applies on the title corresponding button at index, on `UITabBar` of `UITabViewController`.

Hence said that, `self.title` applies on the object holding the `viewController`.